# Can have 2 or more intent in one activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to get the location through gps from another activity, different than the main. And I need to make another activity, a JSON parser. So, I want to know if there is a way to have the separated intents and onActivityResult of each activity. I don't know if I explain me well.

I need to do it like this because I use a AsyncTask for each new activity.

Thank for your help.

Comment: yes you can have million intents in one activity

Answer (score 0):

Use requests ID to differentiate multiple activities results:

```
startActivityForResult(userLoginIntent, ACTIVITY_1_REQUEST_CODE);
```

And in onActivityResult :

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case ACTIVITY_1_REQUEST_CODE:
            // Process the activity 1 results
            break;
            case ACTIVITY_2_REQUEST_CODE:
            // Process the activity 2 results
            break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode,
>   Intent data)

The method takes three parameters -

**requestCode** - The integer request code originally supplied to startActivityForResult(), allowing you to identify who this result came from.
**resultCode**  - The integer result code returned by the child activity through its setResult().
**data**-   An Intent, which can return result data to the caller (various data can be attached to Intent "extras").

You may like to use **the** first parameter - **requestCode**

Reference - [onActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29)